# Jquery checkbox check and uncheck on hover

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net, checkbox

I am using C# code for dynamically creating Check boxes & add them to placeholder and I used Jquery to check/uncheck them on hover event of mouse.

C#:

```
for (j = d; j < b; j++) {

    plhdr_seat.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td>"));
    // CheckBox fg = new CheckBox();
    plhdr_seat.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td>"));
    HtmlInputCheckBox cb = new HtmlInputCheckBox();
    cb.Attributes.Add("class", "mew");
    cb.Checked = true; // or cb.Checked = false;
    cb.ID = "check_" + j.ToString();
    plhdr_seat.Controls.Add(cb);

    plhdr_seat.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td>"));
}
```

jquery:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".mew").mouseover(function () {                
            var attr = $(this).attr("Checked");                               
            if (typeof attr !== typeof undefined && attr !== false)
            {
                $(this).prop('checked', false); // will check the checkbox with id check1                   
            }
            else {
                $(this).prop('checked', true); // will uncheck the checkbox with id check1                  
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have got this. 
[image]

On hover the check boxes are unchecked. But I hover on them once again, they are not checked. 
I can't identify the problem. Help me please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(".mew").on("mouseover", function () {
    this.checked = ! this.checked;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="mew" />
```

Comment: this code works fine in stackoverflows' compiler. but not in my visual studio

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify it to this using [**.hover()**](http://api.jquery.com/hover/):

```js
$(".mew").hover(function() {
  $(this).prop("checked", !$(this).prop("checked"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="mew" />
```

**References**

[.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `.on`

for eg if `<div id="fixed_static">` is div holding all the `checkbox`

Try this

```
$("#fixed_static").on("mouseover",".mew",function(){


});
```

or you can use

```
$("html").on("mouseover",".mew",function(){


    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(document).on("mouseover",".mew",function(){
    this.checked = !this.checked;// check if uncheck, uncheck if checked
    //$(this).prop('checked',!this.checked); in jquery
});
```